# Hibernate Search call to SearchFactory optimize does not invoke immediately

Tags: hibernate-search

I'm trying to call [SearchFactory optimize](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.5/api/org/hibernate/search/SearchFactory.html#optimize%28%29) to run a scheduled index maintenance job (compacting segments - the application is a write intensive). But it does not seem to invoke immediately until I shutdown the Tomcat. My code is calling simply like this.

```
public synchronized void optimizeIndexes() {
    getFullTextEntityManager().flushToIndexes(); //apply any changes before optimizing
    getFullTextEntityManager().getSearchFactory().optimize();
    logger.info("[Lucene] optimization has performed on all the indexes...");
}
```

Comment: why do you think the operation does only get applied when you shutdown Tomcat? Also the benefit of index optimization is low with the latest versions of Lucene.

Comment: I found out getSearchFactory().optimize() call get applied only after Tomcat shutdown is by chance. In my application, I have a use case such that I need to make force merge segments manually at sudden point. [HSearch doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e7497) says I can do that by calling SearchFactory optimize. In ExplicitOnlyOptimizerStrategy, IndexWriter only performs forceMerge(1, true) but no commit. I guess this must the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work around by loaning IndexWriter from HSearch backend.

```
private synchronized void optimizeBareMetal() {
    try {
        LuceneBackendQueueProcessor backend = (LuceneBackendQueueProcessor) getIndexManager().getBackendQueueProcessor();
        LuceneBackendResources resources = backend.getIndexResources();
        AbstractWorkspaceImpl workspace = resources.getWorkspace();
        IndexWriter indexWriter = workspace.getIndexWriter();
        indexWriter.forceMerge(1, true);
        indexWriter.commit();
    } catch (LockObtainFailedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private synchronized DirectoryBasedIndexManager getIndexManager() {
    SearchFactoryImplementor searchFactory = (SearchFactoryImplementor) getFullTextEntityManager().getSearchFactory();
    IndexManagerHolder indexManagerHolder = searchFactory.getIndexManagerHolder();
    return (DirectoryBasedIndexManager) indexManagerHolder.getIndexManager(getEntityClass().getName());
}
```